# Direct Way to Access External Storage from Computer with ADB (Android 10)

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-10.0, adb

For Android 10 phone. I'm looking for a direct way to access external storage from the computer with ADB.

The path is here. But it doesn't seem to have a stable naming. I want this to be valid for another device.

1:daisy:/ $ cd storage

2:daisy:/storage $ ls

3:1606-1548 emulated self

I think this is not the right method. The solutions I found on the internet did not work for me.
    cd $EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: While the non-English sentence seems to repeat the title, please stick to English. I don't understand what `road` you refer to.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was translating. road = path

Answer (score 0):

just try 
adb root 
adb pull /storage/self

self folder  would be containing  ur sd card files